# Get the "Index name" of the multidimensional array with smarty foreach or section

Tags: php, smarty

I got this array ($packageData) of domains and their "configurations":

```
Array (1)
  263 => Array (55)
    example.com => Array (1)
      ssl => true
    example2.com => Array (1)
      ssl => false
```

I want to access the array that is inside and get domain name and potentially its config.
So in simple words, I want to run with foreach or section and get "example.com" and if SSL is "true/false"

So i got this smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$packageData[$serviceid] item=foo} 
    <div class="" id="table-data">
      <div id="table-data-entry">
        <label style="font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 0;" class="">אין מידע</label>
        <span style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 15px;" class="">{$foo[ssl]}</span>
      </div>                        
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

$serviceid is the 263 in this example, it gets the value according to customer's UUID.

I tried 4-5 different solutions but can't find the right one that will get me the domain name and ture/false if its SSL.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you also need to show the site name. The foreach syntax is the same as in PHP.

```
{foreach $packageData[$serviceid] as $siteName => $siteData} 
    <div class="" id="table-data">
      <div id="table-data-entry">
        <label style="font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 0;" class="">אין מידע</label>
        <span style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 15px;" class="">{$siteName}</span>  
        <span style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 15px;" class="">{$siteData['ssl'] ? 'true' : 'false'}</span>
      </div>                        
    </div>
   {foreachelse}
    <div class="" id="table-data">
      <div id="table-data-entry">
          No site data for this service.
      </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for some reason i get blank page, as if i got error 500 (syntax error).
I use Smarty 3.1.36.

You should fix the answer to:
$packageData[$serviceid] as $siteName => $siteData

Comment: @StasKarpinsky Ya fixed by adding the 'as' keyword

Comment: I guess that use of `foreach` in smarty is wrong. You need to specify item and key. See my response.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP It works fine on the projects that I've written in. The doc does show same syntax https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl You can revoke your downvote(if you did)

Comment: @nice_dev I'm so sorry, YES it works since Smarty v.3. I tried to revoked my downvote, but I can't, it says answer must be edited before I can revoke my beacuse it was more than 6 hours ago. So edit it and I'll try again.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP No worries. Edited just now. Also feel free to edit any of my answers if it improves it in someway.

Comment: @nice_dev Revoked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consult Smarty documentation about `foreach`?

As well as you specify a var name for `item`, you can do it for `key`.

So, here is how:

```
{foreach from=$packageData[$serviceid] item=foo key=domain}
    <div class="" id="table-data">
      <div id="table-data-entry">
        <label style="font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 0;" class="">{$domain}</label>
        <span style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 15px;" class="">{$foo[ssl]}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Also, you can use a more current syntax for the `foreach` declaration, this way:

```
{foreach $packageData[$serviceid] as $domain => $foo}
    <div class="" id="table-data">
      <div id="table-data-entry">
        <label style="font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 0;" class="">{$domain}</label>
        <span style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 15px;" class="">{$foo[ssl]}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```